# How do you use list properties in Google App Engine datastore in Java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

An object to be placed in the datastore will have a set of tags.

```
public class Model 
{
    List<String> tagList
    ...
}
```

In Python, the Google App Engine has the notion of list properties.  What is the equivalent notion in Java (if it exists) and how would you use list properties in Java, in JPA and/or in JDO?

Comment: i hope the answer is NOT to use Python!

Comment: anyone know of a JPA implementation?

Comment: there are other options of data access API besides JPA and JDO available with Java, e.g Objectify.

Comment: JPA implementation in GAE/J is obviously GAE's own plugin for DataNucleus. Beware though that this uses an ancient version of DataNucleus and doesn't try to support all JPA features, whereas it ought to be possible to handle the vast majority using BigTable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See my blog post exactly on this: [Efficient Keyword Search with Relation Index Entities and Objectify for Google Datastore](http://novyden.blogspot.com/2011/02/efficient-keyword-search-with-relation.html). It talks about implementing search with list properties using Relation Index Entities and Objectify.

To summarize:

```
  Query<DocumentKeywords> query = ofy.query(DocumentKeywords.class);
  for (String keyword : keywords) {
    query = query.filter("keywords", keyword);
  }

  Set<Key<Document>> keys = query.<Document>fetchParentKeys();

  Collection<Document> documents = ofy.get(keys).values();
```

where `DocumentKeywords` contains a list property (collection) of all keywords for its `Document` entity, and `Document` entity is a parent for `DocumentKeywords`.

Answer (score 3):

In [JDO](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/relationships.html)  use

```
@Persistent
private List<ContactInfo> contactInfoSets;
```